# Using QSqlTableModel to display an SQL view

Tags: c++, database, qt, model-view-controller

I am working on an application which has a view which generates a report to display to the user. This report is something which I'm needing to filter. Using the SQL support in Qt I've tried using QSqlTableModel with its filtering capabilities, but it doesn't seem to find the view as I get the error "Unable to find table TABLE_NAME". How does one model a view in Qt? I've not been able to find any information specifically on that.

```
QSqlDatabase connection(Request_Connection("DB Name"));
QSqlTableModel* pStore(new QSqlTableModel(NULL, connection));

if (connect(connection))
    pStore->setTable("ViewName");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u have an error "Unable to find table TABLE_NAME" it just means that you are trying to get data from non existing table. Check your database.

EDIT

Okay, that's weird what u have done. It should more looks like this:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setDatabaseName("customdb");
db.setUserName("root");
db.setPassword("root");
if(!db.open())
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Error", "Couldn't open database!");
```

That's for open database. In first quotes you have a name of sql which you use. [Here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqldatabase.html#QSqlDatabase) you can found all available sql plugins. When you connect to database, you can read some data. If you want to use QSqlTableModel for this, you can do it this way:

```
QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(parentObject, db);
model->setTable("employee");
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->select();
model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Name"));
model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Salary"));

QTableView *view = new QTableView;
view->setModel(model);
view->hideColumn(0); // don't show the ID
view->show();
```

This simple example will load 'Name' and 'Salary' columns from 'employee' table and will display it in 'view' QTableView. That's how you should do it.

Comment: The first thing I did was to make sure I was connecting to the correct database. Which I am, as the same connection prior retrieves the look-up key just fine for the view.

Comment: The weirdness comes from the macro which wraps an add/return current database and a function which connects to the various databases. I've inherited an "interesting" database design.

Comment: I added the EditStrategy to the code, and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My Advice:

1. Check your database name.
2. I've found this website helpful for understanding QSqlTableModel better
   http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qsqltablemodel.html